# angularjs$http.get and java api call

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, rest

I'm trying to make an angularjs $http.get request with parameters but it's not working due to syntaxt may be. Can you please
confirm what i'm doing wrong , maybe syntax is wrong in angularjs call or in java api method

```
$http.get(document.requestPathPrefix + "/home/my-api",
   $scope.requestParametersObject
   ).then(
        function(response) {
           $scope.output = response.data;
        },
        function(response) {
           $scope.retrieveErrorMssg = "Failed to retrieve required data.";
   });
```

**my parameters are like in this image**

[parameter object for api call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eoy6Q.png)

**And in java api call like this**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/my-api", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Collection<MyObjectResponse>> getMyObjResponse(@RequestBody final MyObjectRequest request)
{
    Map<Integer,MyObjectResponse> oResponse = new HashMap<>();
    try {

        //Manipulation and db calls

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<Collection<MyObjectResponse>>(oResponse.values(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Why did you made a get request rather than creating a post request?

Comment: per my understanding i can use get or post both in this scenario

Answer (score 1):

try ,

```
$http({
                url: '/home/my-api',
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                data: JSON.stringify(request)
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                return null;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about syntax, take a look at this simple example and modify it to your need.

In JS, your http.get call should contain the URL and its parameters if any,

```
$http.get('getUserInfo',
{
   params : {
          'userEmail' : 'userEmail'
   }
}).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
});
```

If you are passing a parameter to the API call, ensure your Java controller or the service has the parameter defined to receive the same. Ideally the parameters should match between the call and the provider

For example, for the above API call, the spring controller should like below,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getUserInfo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody User getUserInfo(
        @RequestParam("userEmail") String userEmail) {
// Do Something
}
```

Comment: my worry is not only the syntax its just if iam passing the parameters from http.get request correctly, i guess there is some wrong format as my java call does'nt get called

Comment: Yes because your parameter should match with the http.get call which is not in your case I believe

Comment: Also ensure if the URL is exactly matching. In your case you have added /home before the API mapping. So when the URL and the parameter matches then it should trigger the API

Comment: url is correct but something is wrong in java method signatures so if any idea please let me know

Comment: In your JS, I see it as /home/my-api and in your controller I see it as /my-api. So Is it correct? Whether /home is a parent level mapping or ?

Comment: It's a typo my bad